# Unable to remove sudo access from ubuntu user

Tags: permissions, sudo, security, users

When i have install ubuntu at that time create `admin` user, Now my plan is to remove `sudo` access from this user and added custom sudofile for this user.

First I remove `sudo` group from this user:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/group | grep admin
admin:x:1000:

$ sudo cat /etc/group | grep sudo
sudo:x:27:
```

Even there is no entry on sudofile :

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep -v "#"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

My custom sudo file :

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/custom | grep -v "#"
Host_Alias HOSTNAME = myhost

Cmnd_Alias ARCH = /bin/tar, /bin/gzip, /bin/gunzip
...
...
root ALL = (ALL) ALL
admin HOSTNAME = NOPASSWD: ARCH,...,...
```

Interesting thing is that to prevent service which not define on `custom`sudo file.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox status
[sudo] password for admin: 
Sorry, user admin is not allowed to execute '/etc/init.d/virtualbox   status' as root on myhost.
```

Issue is that, still  able to edit `/etc` folder and created another `test` user which working fine means who can't edit `/etc` and other operations !

My goal is to privent to edit `/etc` directory but able to access `/var/log/` and other general directory and operation, here we can define `service` to allow but Can we define the directory and any other way ?

Comment: Why don't add that [ configuration ] to the already existing sudo file ?

Comment: @George Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: This looks like a rehash of [your previous question](/q/906868/175814). If you want to create a user account that can start and stop services and read log files without full super-user privileges, *please do precisely that*. Don't create completely new sudoers rules from scratch if all you want to do is *grant or revoke user privileges*. See [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](/q/159007/175814)